# LandTrendr spectral-temporal (LT - GEE) in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth

I've been trying to use LT-GEE in study for restoration area. But, I get some error

> Required argument (timeSeries) missing to function: TemporalSegmentation.LandTrendr(timeSeries, maxSegments, spikeThreshold, vertexCountOvershoot, preventOneYearRecovery, recoveryThreshold, pvalThreshold, bestModelProportion, minObservationsNeeded)

Even when I used the correct module from LT-GEE:

> var ltgee = require('users/emaprlab/public:Modules/LandTrendr.js');

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are not providing the required argument `timeSeries` into the function. Also, you should use the provided `ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegementation.LandTrendr()` to get you result. This function is provided by the Earth Engine and LandTrendr teams on the platform (here is the [article](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/10/5/691) describing it).

I have provided example code that uses yearly Landsat 8 as an input into the algorithm:

```
// get a landsat collection with cloud masked data
var landsat = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR").map(function(img){
  var qa = img.select('pixel_qa');
  var cloudMask = qa.bitwiseAnd(Math.pow(5,2)).eq(0);
  var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('ndvi');
  return img.addBands(ndvi).updateMask(cloudMask);
});
print('Landsat Collection:',landsat.limit(100));

// specify start and end year
var startYear = 2013;
var endYear = 2018;

// map over each year to get a composite
var yearlyComp = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List.sequence(startYear,endYear).map(function(i){
  var t1 = ee.Date.fromYMD(ee.Number(i),1,1);
  var t2 = t1.advance(1,'year');
  return landsat.filterDate(t1,t2).qualityMosaic('ndvi').set('system:time_start',t1.millis());
})).sort('system:time_start');

// display one composite on map
Map.addLayer(ee.Image(yearlyComp.first()),{min:50,max:5500,bands:'B7,B5,B3',gamma:1.5},'Composite Image');

// specify parameters for LandTrendr algorithm
var run_params = { 
  maxSegments:            6,
  spikeThreshold:         0.9,
  vertexCountOvershoot:   3,
  preventOneYearRecovery: true,
  recoveryThreshold:      0.25,
  pvalThreshold:          0.05,
  bestModelProportion:    0.75,
  minObservationsNeeded:  6
};
// add timeSeries key and variable to dict
run_params.timeSeries = yearlyComp.select('ndvi');

// run the algorithm
var result = ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.LandTrendr(run_params);

// print results and add to Map
print('LandTrendr Result:',result);
Map.addLayer(result,{min:startYear,max:endYear},'LandTrendr Result');
```

This code gets a result but needs extra post processing to access what you probably need. Please see the documentation for full examples: https://emapr.github.io/LT-GEE/

Comment: Thanks for help me, mr.Market, specially for send the article. I' trying to understand what axactly each parametrer does for the targets I wish better understand, which are restoration areas.

Comment: Hello. I'm trying to use LT-GEE with LANDSAT-07/SR images collection, watching vegetation and silviculture targets with NDVI INDEX. The returned values are really incompatibles, demonstrating negative numbers Can you guide me if the is about how I filtering the collecction? Heres is the code [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/387dbba4e047a23857b956f8c0d795fc)